# view::make not redirecting to specified page (laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, laravel, view

I am using laravel 4.2

The file *Route.php* contains this:

```
Route::get('/purchase_invoices/{PURCHASEQUOTATION_ID}/copyfromquote',
           'PurchaseInvoicesController@copyfromquote');
```

and my function does this:

```
public function copyfromquote($id) {
    return View::make('purchase_invoices.create');
}
```

When I navigate to http://localhost/purchase_invoices/8/copyfromquote,
I get screen with message

> This web page is not available
>   ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

[image]

I am clueless.

I am using the same method with other URLs, and it works. I only have the problem with `purchase_invoices`.

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your error page?

Comment: What you take a screen shot of your files structure in views?

Comment: You can insert that inside your question.

Comment: yes i have done it.please check

Comment: Can i see the file structure in your views?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: file structure attached here,Please help me here. from last 2 weeks i am not done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
 Route::get('/purchase_invoices/{PURCHASEQUOTATION_ID}', array(   
'as' =>'choose a named route',  
'uses' =>'PurchaseInvoicesController@copyfromquote'  
 ));
```

And show us the Blade page:

From other posts in SO:

Check your syntax in your blade page: It could be the following:

The Blade inside of your Blade comments are still being parsed into PHP. The PHP end tags inside of the PHP block-comment is causing the PHP parser to end early, resulting in some badly formed PHP/HTML that could be crashing your connection (likely caused by the dangling */ ?>).

Comment: yes exactly same in blade in have missed the @elseif bracket not closed. but it was not showing me error.I was very surprised . Thank you very much for solving my problem.